# I can't catch the SqlException using try-catch

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to catch the SqlException using try-catch so I wrote this code:

```
public async Task Open()
    {
        try
        {
            if (sqlconnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => sqlconnection.OpenAsync()).ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ec)
        {
          XtraMessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
        }
    }
public async Task<DataTable> SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {

        using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stored_procedure))
            {
                return null;
            }

            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

            if (param != null)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }

            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => da.Fill(dt)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    catch(SqlException ec)
                    {
                        XtraMessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }

    }
```

But unfortunately that did't work and always I get error on  da.Fill(dt)  with this message

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>     HResult=0x80131904
>     Message=Une erreur liée au réseau ou spécifique à l'instance s'est produite lors de l'établissement d'une connexion à SQL Server. Le serveur est introuvable ou n'est pas accessible. Vérifiez que le nom de l'instance est correct et que SQL Server est configuré pour autoriser les connexions distantes. (provider: Interfaces réseau SQL, error: 26 - Erreur lors de la localisation de Server/Instance spécifié)
>     Source=Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
>     StackTrace:
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, String certificate, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, Boolean useOriginalAddressInfo, Boolean disableTnir, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>      at Smart_Industrial_Management.DAL.DataAccessLayerV550.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.b__0() in C:\Users\MBoua\source\repos\SIM Windows7\Smart Industrial Management\DAL\DataAccessLayerV550.cs:line 116
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, bool, System.Action)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, bool, bool)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds, bool, long, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationMethod, string, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback, bool, bool, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, string, System.Security.SecureString, bool, Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer, bool, bool, bool)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, string, System.Security.SecureString, bool, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, string, System.Security.SecureString, bool)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.SqlInternalConnectionTds(Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, object, string, System.Security.SecureString, bool, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SessionData, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback, Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, string, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo, bool, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager)
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object, Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
    Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
    Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

I use it in this way
I have Created a class with this name CLS_VoortmanV550 and i put this code:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetV550Batch()
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayerV550 DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayerV550();

        using (DataTable dt = await Task.Run(() => DAL.SelectData("GetV550Batch", null)).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            DAL.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

and from the form i call this method

```
 try
        {
            gridControl3.DataSource = await clsV550.GetV550Batch().ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
        catch
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(Resources.FailedConnectV550, Resources.error, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Use the debugger. It will tell you where exactly the exception happens, which very likely isn’t inside your try-catch statement.

Comment: @ASh I already use using DataTable dt = new DataTable() and about trying to catch the exception where sqlconnection is opened did't work to

Comment: @ckuri it happened inside try-catch in this line of code:await Task.Run(() => da.Fill(dt)).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: And what happens if you step to next statements (usually the F10 key)? The exception should be rethrown by the await (with a different stacktrace) and then caught by the catch.

Comment: The error message you posted doesn’t seem complete because it is missing the expected stacktrace which should at least mention the Fill method you called, and the Tasks stacktrace. It looks more like a [first chance exception message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/) which Visual Studio shows just for your information _before_ it actually executes the catch block.

Comment: Judging by the error number (I don't speak French), this is a connection problem, which can only happen during `Open()`. So, could you show us the code which calls `Open()`? Does it use `await` on `Open()`? Also, `ConfigureAwait(false)` should not be used if you expect to return to the UI thread after `await` - does `XtraMessageBox.Show` expect to be executed on the UI thread?

Comment: @ckuri Yes when i use F10 key the exception caught by the catch .I have add full message to my question

Comment: Correction: `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` can also open the connection, so is there a reason to share `Open()` with us?

Comment: @ Branko Dimitrijevic In case of any other mistake

Comment: "Yes when i use F10 key the exception caught by the catch" - so the exception *is* being caught, contrary to your title? I don't understand what you're looking for in this question - are you trying to understand how the exception is propagated, or why you're getting an exception in the first place? It's worth separating those two concerns.

Comment: @ Branko Dimitrijevic Yes the XtraMessageBox.Show expect to be executed on the UI thread ,I have update my question please see it

Comment: i am trying to do something and I expect something else .
I am expecting from visual studio to jump directly to message box when the error is thrown,Now I feel so stupid.
I rebuild my application and I run the exe file all thing are perfect.
I am truely sorry and فhanks for giving me your precious time

Answer (score 0):

You should never have User-Interface Interaction in Background Tasks.
And the Task class is designed to do so.

You are waiting for the completion of the Task.
After the Task has ended you can check on

```
 Task.IsSuccessfullCompleted
 Task.IsCancelled
```

etc.
In case of Exceptions you will find the exceptions here.

```
 Task.AggregateException
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception?view=netframework-4.8

This will contain information about occured exceptions, maybe multiple.

So this try-catch-pattern should generally not be used across threads.

If you do exception-handling inside your Task, log them somewhere, but do not come up with MessagesBoxes. Talking to the user is the job of the Foreground-Thread.